# I'm having trouble with flutter doctor not finding android licenses Android SDK Command-line Tools didn´t work

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor, android-licenses

[After getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3YJ1.png)
I tried solutions I could find and installed Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) from android studio and tried running flutter doctor again and got [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPdF.png) (translation: could not find or load main class).

Answer (score -1):

Open your android studio> tools> system settings> android sdk> select android sdk command line tools,  ..build tools, ..sdk platform tools, ..sdk tools > Click OK.
Also take a note of the sdk installation location given on top. You might need it further.

**Please post the result of `flutter doctor -v` from a command prompt if you need further help.**

Comment: this didn't work, all those tools were already installed, I tried unnistalling them and installing them again but when running flutter doctor and  flutter doctor --android-licenses again the same errors showed up.

Comment: This issue has been solved by the above steps before. If you couldn't provide more information in the questions, that is all how people could try to help. Also, I have asked you for posting the result of a more detailed flutter doctor output (not the usual one, Note that the command I have given in the answer has an extra parameter). You can post those too if you want specific help.